# Using numpy arrays in a function which already uses numpy arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

For my programming exercise I have to plot different trajectories of objects on different planets. I do this by calculating the x-positions and y-positions. To get a trajectory I need to use linspace (0 to 30 seconds with 100 points). 
I tried calculating the x-positions like this:

```
def calcXPos():
    xPos = (velocities * np.cos(angles)) * np.linspace(0,30,100)
    return xPos
```

Here velocities and angles are one-dimensional numpy arrays. However if I run this I get an error saying the dimensions aren't right (It's trying to multiply each element of the arrays which don't have the same dimension). My question is: How do make this such that I get back a big array with of size (n, 100) where n is the amount of starting velocities and angles?

Thanks in advance,

Mees

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a loop? Assuming that there are the same number of velocities and angles, the following would work:

```
def calcXPos():
    xPos = []
    temp = (velocities * np.cos(angles))
    for i in np.linspace(0,30,100):
        xPos.append(i*temp)

    return xPos
```

If this isn't what you're looking for can you clarify the question a bit, please?

Comment: Since this worked, can you please accept it as an answer to help others in the future. Thank you!